# Using EEA matrix, find a solution of:

Tags: number-theory

Using EEA matrix, find a solution of:

100x + 167y = 33

I tried this and i got the answer of: x = 2 and y = -1

But i dont understand why this is.

Answer (score 1):

EEA stands for Extended Euclidean Algorithm. EA is used to find the greatest common divisor, or gcd.
$$167=1*100+67$$
$$100=1*67+33$$
$$67=2*33+1$$

One way to find x and y is to substitute back $67$ as $100-33$ into the first equation. Now instead of working backwards, the EEA matrix carries out the operation as you go through the Euclidean Algorithm. Eventually arriving at a form $ax+by=r$, r is the remainder at that step.

I suggest you read up on Bezout's identity and EA to get a more comprehensive understanding since the number may not always show up in the carried out EA and you may have to multiply a number to get to the final result.